# In react, can a component know whether its parent has disabled it or not?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

Disable meaning to set `display: none`. The component needs to know to do something when it is enabled, so it needs this information.

Comment: With functional components, return a cleanup function from a `useEffect` function. It gets called when the component will unmount. `useEffect(() => { return () => { /* clean up here */ } }, []);`

Comment: You can create a `disabled` (boolean type) value in parent's state and pass it to the child component as a prop. E.g. `<ChildComp foo="bar" disabled={disabled }/>`. And now, `ChildComp` can access `disabled` value and do something based on its value.